# Renv with docker. How to use local renv cache for packages in docker?

Tags: r, docker, renv

I am trying to build docker image for a R project. I created environment with renv for this project to lock state of packages that I used during this project.
How can I build docker image for this project and use the renv cache of my local machine instead of R-cran?
I hope I was clear.

Thank for advance

Comment: Is this the issue you have? https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues/400 If you find a solution, could you post it here? Cheers!